# Why is my date wrong with Carbon::createFromFormat()?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

When I create the Carbon object from an existing string, it is making a completely wrong date out of it.

```
$dateString = "2022-04-01 21:24:00";
$carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateString);
echo $carbon->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

and this outputs:

```
2023-12-01 21:12:00
```

Totally lost here. This doesn't make sense.

*Edit: Nevermind. I am an idiot and my format in the real code was "Y-m-d H:**m**:s"

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the posted code.

Comment: The output of the posted code is "2022-04-01 21:24:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code that you post it's not what you are using
it seems month is using minutes

so 24 as month become 12 of the next year

probably you are using "Y-m-d H:m:s" instead of "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typo. It worked of course. :)